# how to install Cordova camera plug in for ios in mac

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app, apache-cordova

How to install Cordova camera  plug in for iOS in mac os 
(my Cordova version is 6.0.0)

i am install Cordova6.0.0  in mac.but i don't know how to install camera plugin?

help me!

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-camera.git
$ cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-media-capture.git
$ cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-media.git
```

Comment: give me any example project.

Comment: @MamtaD- Before reviewing, make yourself clear or gather a little knowledge of cardova. These are the command used in terminal not a link.

Comment: cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera